# Please, use the flagging system

Tags: discussion, flagging

Lately, with our increase in popularity, that also means an increase in those who want to just have some fun with the site.

Namely new users who just want to post obscene items, or spam bots that just post advertisements.

However, I see users just commenting on these posts and leaving them alone (*maybe* downvoting them).

I implore you, if you see this kind of behaviour, and you have the ability to, **Flag it for removal**.

All of the moderators currently are in the relatively same timezone, an hour apart and if this stuff goes up while we are sleeping (insert obligatory, 'Mods are asleep, post ponies' post here), we have a harder time catching it, assuming the system doesn't flag it automatically.

If they get flagged by users, we can take care of the spam much quicker.  In fact, if a post receives about 5 or so spam votes, it is **automatically deleted**

**END TRANSMISSION**